# How to compress the image file size when it is in the folder

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to compress the image file size to a max of 100kb, but the user can upload an image with a max size of 4MB, when entering the folder the image size becomes <100kb or max 100kb.

[image]

Below is my config code:

```php
$config['upload_path']      = './assets/uploads/STNK/';
$config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
$config['max_size']         = '4000'; /* users can upload 4MB files */
$config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload('foto_stnk')) {
    $old_image = $this->data['row']->foto_stnk;
    unlink(FCPATH . './assets/uploads/STNK/' . $old_image);

    $new_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $this->db->set('foto_stnk', $new_image);
} else {
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: what have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you want to reduce the quality of the image in order to reduce the amount of space required to store its data, or just try to store it in a more compressed format, or what? Most image formats are effectively already a compressed format, so your main option is probably to reduce the quality and/or size of the image. There are image manipulation tools available to PHP.

Comment: you need to **resize** the image, that format (jpg) is already compressed. one can resize the image client-side or server-side on upload before save or before serving the file or a mix.

Comment: @ADyson i just want to compress the image file size, but not the format... is it possible?

Comment: If you want to reduce the file size, then, with an image, your options are to reduce size or quality, or both, so that there is less information which needs to be stored about the image. As explained above, image formats already use compression algorithms innately in the file creation process, so (for example) putting it through a compression process such as ZIP would have little or no effect.

Comment: [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+compress+jpg) should get you started, for JPEGs at least.

Comment: only JPEGs? can not all formats?

Answer (score 0):

You can user imagejpeg() function of php to reduce image quality.
This might help you : [imgejpegfunction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)